# How to set a variable in where clause of Select query in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

while executing the below query i'm not getting sucess value

```
$name=qwe;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM USER WHERE name = $name");
```

Instead of above query if i put the below, I can able to get the appropriate ans:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM USER WHERE name = 'qwe'");
```

Can anyone give a solution for my first query??

Comment: Add quotes around `$name`, like this: `$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM USER WHERE name = '" . $name . "'");`

Answer (score 0):

Close the variable in quote and concatenate the string into query

```
$name= "qwe";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM USER WHERE name = '".$name."'");
```

one more note
please use mysqli for security purposes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM USER WHERE name = '".$name."'");
```

P.S. I have not tested the above code but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table_name where col_name = '".$variable."'
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could edit your answer and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Answer (score 0):

Directly use :

```
$name = 'qwe';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE name = '$name'");
```

And on more advise, you should never use mysql_* functions now as they have been deprecated in newer versions of PHP and will produce the notices.